# Anyone know how to put a Cygwin term in the context menu

Tags: windows, cygwin, contextmenu

I would like to put a Cygwin terminal menu item on a Windows 7 context menu.

But I would like the shell to open at the folder.

chere -i is supposed to do something like it but ends up giving a bash shell that does NOT have my profiles loaded.

Anyone know how to acheive this?

Comment: I've just tried `chere -i` and the resulting `Bash prompt here` context menu item gives me a fully loaded login shell. I'm on Win7 with Cygwin 1.7.20. So I could not reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `chere -i -t mintty`. It worked for me, as it defines which terminal type to bring up, and in my case, (I'm running 64 bit windows 7) mintty seems to load my profiles.

Since you have already tried `chere -i`, you have to uninstall it first, using `chere -u`, then run the above command `chere -i -t mintty`.

Bare in mind, that on my work laptop, I had to run cygwin as administrator for this to work (I believe chere modifies the registry at some point). But it worked on my home PC flawlessly without administrator privileges.

Other people also claim some success following this blog post, http://with-love-from-siberia.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/cygwin-here.html which shows how to use a windows batch file to modify the registry to add the option to the folder context menu.